# operator overloading and the usage of const_cast

Tags: c++, operator-overloading, constants

For the following code snippet,

```
class A{
  const int a;
  public:
  A(): a(0){}
  A(int m_a):a(m_a){};
  A& operator =(const A &other);
};
A & A::operator =(const A &other)
{
  const_cast<int&>(a) = other.a;
  return *this;
}
```

what do the lines of

```
A & A::operator =(const A &other)
```

```
const_cast<int&>(a) = other.a;
```

mean? Or why this operator is defined this way?  In other words, I feel confused about its usage and the way it is defined/written.

Comment: In this line -- `A(int m_a):a(m_a){};` -- the normal idiom of m_ being prepended to member variables is reversed. The argument to the constructor has the m_ and the member variable doesn't.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `const_cast` removes the `const` from the `const` member `a`, thus allowing the assignment from `other.a` to succeed (without the `const_cast` the type of `a` would be `const int`, and thus it wouldn't be modifiable).

Probably the idea is that `a` is initialized at class construction and can't be modified "by design" in any other place, but the author of the class decided to make an exception for assignment.

I have mixed feelings against this piece of code, very often the use of a `const_cast` is a symptom of bad design, on the other hand it can be logical to allow assignment but retain the `const` for all the other operations.

Comment: This is kinda like trying to implement move semantics pre-rvalue references - take a `const` object and assign yourself whatever resource it is managing and then modify a `mutable` flag in the source object to indicate it no longer manages the resource. Feels ugly but it was the only way to get it done.

Comment: IMO, it means more like: `a` is const ... but anyone can modify it anywhere (`*this = A(some_value)`)

Answer (score 0):

a is a const member variable.  [const_cast](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bz6at95h%28v=vs.80%29.aspx)(a) bypasses the const-correctness rules. Otherwise, you could only assign a in the initializer list of the constructor.